# PHP OpenSSL extension not working while installing TYPO3 CMS 7.4.0

Tags: php, windows, apache, typo3, php-openssl

While installing TYPO3 CMS 7.4.0 I get the message:

PHP OpenSSL extension not working
Something went wrong while trying to create a new private key for testing. Please check the integration of the PHP OpenSSL extension and if it is installed correctly.

Win 8.1 x64; PHP Version 5.6.12 VC11 x86 Thread Safe; Apache 2.4.16 VC11 Win32

I've read about similar issues and done everything recommended, but the problem is still here.

What I've done is:

- uncommented in php.ini
  `extension=php_openssl.dll`
- checked in phpinfo() that openssl is enabled: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf7CF.png
- added an environment variable "OPENSSL_CONF" with values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBtCB.png
- set path to 'openssl.exe':

  - set $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['binSetup'] in
    ...\typo3\sysext\core\Configuration\DefaultConfiguration.php
    to 'openssl=C:\Apache24\bin\openssl.exe'
- appended C:\Apache24\bin\ to the environment variable PATH
- restarted apache/rebooted PC.

And nothing helped.

1. What else would you recommend to check?
2. How to execute the function `openssl_pkey_new()` using cmd and check if there's a problem with openssl?

**EDIT:**

1. I've carefully read openssl.installation manual from official php site (sry, am not able to post more than 2 links due to lack of reputation here ^^) and nothing helped
2. When I run this script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);$test = openssl_pkey_new();echo $test;`

I get a blank page in my browser (while 'display_errors = On' and 'display_startup_errors = On' in php.ini)

3. Installed XAMPP.

In the shell on XAMPP control panel, openssl command gives

> WARNING: can't open config file: C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf OpenSSL>

While openssl.cnf is located in C:/xampp/apache/conf/openssl.cnf
And in PHP Variables there's `_SERVER["OPENSSL_CONF"]   C:/xampp/apache/conf/openssl.cnf`

In the CMD openssl command gives

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>openssl WARNING: can't open config file:
>   D:\tmp\openssl-1.0.1p\vc11\x86/openssl.cnf OpenSSL>

4. Both libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are of version 1.0.1.16 and are the same in apache/bin and /php
5. There's `SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/conf/openssl.cnf"` in httpd-xampp.conf

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try all optiones mentioned here: http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php
2. You can use `php -a` to open a php shell and run the mentioned command. Or you can write yourself a minimalistic php file and run that from your browser:

   ```
   <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $test = openssl_pkey_new();
   echo $test;
   ```

Comment: Hello, pgampe and a big thank you for your reply! I get a blank page using this script. Spent several hours to understand, what's wrong - failed to pierce the cause. Sorry, I am a newbie yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A blank page means a PHP error. The default error handling is to simply serve a blank page if an error occours. You can find more about this by searching for ``blank page php``. Please consult your PHP error log for details about the error.